# How to verify number of calls method of 'this' service

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I'm using NUnit framework with moq for testing. I've got a problem with veryfing how many times private method of this class has been called. To do so with mock object it's enough to call Verify() with parameters of type Times, but my method is part of this class. I was trying to mock current service (SUT), but it probably isn't the best idea and it doesn't work properly.

SUT:

```
public object Post(Operations.Campaign.Merge request)
{
    List<CampaignIdWithNumberOfAds> campaignList = new List<CampaignIdWithNumberOfAds>();

        for (int i = 0; i < request.CampaignIdsToMerge.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.CampaignRepository.Exist(request.CampaignIdsToMerge[i]))
            {
                campaignList.Add(new CampaignIdWithNumberOfAds()
                {
                    CampaignId = request.CampaignIdsToMerge[i],
                    NumberOfAdvertisement = this.CampaignRepository.GetNumberOfAdvertisementsInCampaign(request.CampaignIdsToMerge[i])
                });
            }
        }

        if (campaignList.Count > 1)
        {
            campaignList = campaignList.OrderByDescending(p => (p == null) ? -1 : p.NumberOfAdvertisement).ToList();
            List<CampaignIdWithNumberOfAds> campaignsToMerge = campaignList.Skip(1).ToList();
            CampaignIdWithNumberOfAds chosenCampaign = campaignList.FirstOrDefault<CampaignIdWithNumberOfAds>();

            uint chosenCampaignId = chosenCampaign.CampaignId;

            foreach (var campaignToMerge in campaignsToMerge)
            {
                this.MergeCampaigns(chosenCampaignId, campaignToMerge.CampaignId);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Test:

```
    [Test]
    public void MergeCampaignsPost_ValidMergeCampaignsRequest_ExecuteMergeCampaignsMethodAppropriateNumberOfTimes() 
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockCampaignService = new Mock<Toucan.Api.Services.CampaignService>();
        var request = Mother.GetValidMergeCampaignsRequest_WithDifferentNumbersOfAdvertisement();
        mockCampaignService.Setup(x => x.MergeCampaigns(It.IsAny<uint>(), It.IsAny<uint>()));

        // Act
        var response = this.Service.Post(request);

        // Assert
        mockCampaignService.Verify(x => x.MergeCampaigns(It.IsAny<uint>(), It.IsAny<uint>()), Times.Exactly(request.CampaignIdsToMerge.Count - 1));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that I won't give you a solution here, although I would rather suggest you some sort of guidance. There are many different strategies to unit testing and different people would suggest different solutions. Basically in my opinion you could change the way you are testing your code (you might agree or disagree with those, but please take them into consideration).

---

- **Unit test should be independent from the implementation**

Easy as it sounds, it is very hard to keep to this approach. Private methods are your implementation of solving the problem. The typical pitfall for a developer writing a unit test for his own code is the fact that you know how your code works and mirror it in unit test. What if the implementation changes, but the public method will still fulfill the requested contract? Hardly ever you want to directly your unit test with a private method. This is related to the following...

- **Test should check the output result of the method**

Which basically means do not check how many times something is executed if you don't have to. I am not sure what is your `MergeCampaigns` method doing but it would be better if you check the result of the operation instead of how many times it is executed.

- **Don't overdo your unit tests - keep it maintainable**

Try to test each functional scenario you can imagine with as simple and as independent test as possible. Don't go too deep checking if something is called. Otherwise, you will get a 100% coverage at start, but you will curse each time changing a thing in your service, because this will make half of your test fail (assuming that the service is still doing its job, but in different way than designed at the beginning). So you will spend time rewriting unit tests that actually give you no gain in terms of creating a bulletproof solution.

---

It is very easy to start writing unit tests and keep the coverage green, it starts to get very tricky if you want to write **good unit tests.** There are many valuable resources to help with that. Good luck!